# Regex matching redundent string bloc

Tags: regex

I was working arround to make a regex that match a certain block of a string, the problem that it contains many similar blocks and its not clearly separted so i can't tell how to stop the regex.

Example of string

```
  A1, \field Do Zone Sizing Calculation
      \note If Yes, Zone sizing is accomplished from corresponding Sizing:Zone objects
      \note and autosize fields.
      \type choice
      \key Yes
      \key No
      \default No
  A1, \field Do Zone Sizing Calculation
      \note If Yes, Zone sizing is accomplished from corresponding Sizing:Zone objects
      \note and autosize fields.
      \type choice
      \key Yes
      \key No
      \default No
```

So what i am trying to do is to match and select only the first A1.
Here what i have done so far:

```
^\s{2}((A\d,|N\d,)|(A\d;|N\d;))(.*?\n\s{2})*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in case any one happens to have the same problem.

```
^\s{2}((A\d,|N\d,)|(A\d;|N\d;)).*\n(\s{6}.*?\n)*
```